# Creating a new div during a while Loop

Tags: php, mysql, css

I have my code written to select images from my database and display them, grouped by month. I would like every 'month of photos' to be in its own "container" div. I cannot figure out how to do this while in a WHILE LOOP. I think I need a way to tell if the next row of data, that is going to get iterated, is a new month or not. Any suggestions?

My code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_COOKIE['user_id']))
{
if (!isset($_GET['user_id']))
{
$user_id= $_COOKIE['user_id'];
}
else
{
$user_id= $_GET['user_id'];
}

$connect= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "si");
$query= "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id= $user_id ORDER BY date DESC";

$result= mysqli_query($connect, $query)
or die('error with query');
$date = "0";

while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

if ($date != $row['date']) {
 echo "<p> ".$row['date']."</p><br/>";
 $date = $row['date'];
}

echo '<img src="'.$row['picture']. '"/>' . "<br/>";
}
}
?>
```

Here is how it should look...

[image]

For example, the FEB 2012 month should be in a different container div than JAN 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite easy to implement this at the same place where you create the month header.

```
$first = true;
if ($date != $row['date']) {
    if ($first) {
        $first = false;
    } else {
        echo "<\div>";
    }
    echo "<div><p> ".$row['date']."</p><br/>";
    $date = $row['date'];
}
```

Then you have to close the last div after the while loop by calling:

```
echo "</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this to check if a new container has been opened or not:

```
<?php

if (isset($_COOKIE['user_id']))
{
if (!isset($_GET['user_id']))
{
$user_id= $_COOKIE['user_id'];
}
else
{
$user_id= $_GET['user_id'];
}

$connect= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "si");
$query= "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id= $user_id ORDER BY date DESC";

$result= mysqli_query($connect, $query)
or die('error with query');
$date = "0";

$firstmonth = true; //used to tell if a div has been opened yet or not

while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

if ($date != $row['date']) {
 if(!$firstmonth){ //close existing row first if needed
    echo "</div>";
    $firstmonth = false;
 }
 echo "<div class="month-container"><p> ".$row['date']."</p><br/>";
 $date = $row['date'];
}

echo '<img src="'.$row['picture']. '"/>' . "<br/>";
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if (isset($_COOKIE['user_id']))
{
if (!isset($_GET['user_id']))
{
$user_id= $_COOKIE['user_id'];
}
else
{
$user_id= $_GET['user_id'];
}

$connect= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "si");
$query= "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id= $user_id ORDER BY date DESC";

$result= mysqli_query($connect, $query)
or die('error with query');

$date = "0";
$it= 0;

while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

if ($date != $row['date']) {
if ($it < 1) {
echo "<div class='container'><p> ".$row['date']."</p><br/>";
 $date = $row['date'];
 $it ++;
    }
else {
 echo "</div><div class='container'><p> ".$row['date']."</p><br/>";
 $date = $row['date'];
 $it ++;
 }
```

}

```
echo '<img src="'.$row['picture']. '"/>' . "<br/>";
}
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Try somthing like this:

```
<?php
for($i =1; $i <= 12; $i++)
{
 $result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `user_id` = '" . $user_id . "' AND `month` = '" . $i . "'"));
 if(count($result))
    {
      // create the container and the images for the current month here
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You can have more than 12 months, as you can display the photos from several years.